# HttpUrlConnection not working on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3

Im making an app that requires the HttpURLConnection. I tested it on the emulator and on my

Optimus S version 2.3.3 but when i test it on my Galaxy S3 version 4.1.2 it automatically fails. The LogCat doesn't show any errors. So im wondering why it fails on the Galaxy S3.

Http Setup

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                    URL check_url = new URL("http://www.website.com");
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) check_url.openConnection();
                        http.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                        http.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
                        http.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        http.connect();
```

Comment: How do you know it failed without logcat errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Android version (I don't known) need an AsyncTask to make HTTP connection, so you must to put your code in a background thread like that.

```
public void makeSingUp(){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
           //Your code connection
           return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            //Some message that indicates the connection was finished, or nothing.
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

download volley lib and add in your project. tutorial [link]: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/
    public class send_data extends AsyncTask {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(main.this);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("please wait...");
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

```
    String url = "http://your_url";
    try {
        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(
                1);
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key for your data","yourdata"));


        String str_responsebody = obj_service.executer(url, nvp);
        Log.i("responce", str_responsebody + "===");
        return str_responsebody;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.i("error1", "" + e.toString());
        return null;
    }

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);



    try {

        Log.i("result", result);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();


            }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error2", "" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}